# How do I reference an object property in a method call in Jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to render a form in a flask app using jinja2 and flask-wtf, but am having trouble figuring out how to handle adding a generated argument for onclick that contains a property as part of it's argument.

You can see in the form label section I have onclick set to call a javascript function and pass the name property of the current loop object and this works as intended. However when I am in the form field section, I need to pass onclick to the loop object as a key word argument, and need to make the argument of my argument the object name property. This doesn't work.

Here is a shortened example:

```
<form class="form">
    {% for entry_field in form %}
        {{ entry_field.label() }}
        {{ entry_field(onclick="jsFunction({{entry_field.name}})}}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Here is a full example:

```
<form id="reg_form" class="form text-left" method="post" role="form">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{% for entry_field in form %}
{% if entry_field != form.csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group row">
    <!--form label-->
    <a href="#" onclick="showNotes('{{entry_field.name}}')">
    {{ entry_field.label(class="col-sm-3 col-form-label") }}
    </a>
    <!--form field-->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        {{ entry_field(class_="form-control", onclick="showNotes('{{entry_field.name}}')") }}
        {% for error in entry_field.errors %}<span style="color: red;">{{ error }}</span>{% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
<!--form submit-->
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried `{{ entry_field(onclick=("jsFunction(%s)" | format(entry_field.name)) }}`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string formatting to build a string you want:

```
{{ "jsFunction(%s)" | format(entry_field.name) }}
```

And that string you can use as the parameter for `entry_field()`:

```
{{ entry_field(onclick=("jsFunction(%s)" | format(entry_field.name)) }}
```